# Can you save PNG's to the photo library in iOS5?

Tags: ios, uiimage, png, photo

I've noticed that line drawings from the drawing app I'm making are very low quality when saved using this code:

```
UIImage *imageToSave = drawImage.image;
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil);
```

As far as I can understand, you can't set the JPG quality when using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum.

Is there a way to save the UIImage as a PNG to the photo library directly, or some way to increase the JPG quality? When doing a screenshot (pressing on/off+home on the iPad) the quality of the grabbed picture is perfect, but I can't expect people to save images that way.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
NSData* pngdata = UIImagePNGRepresentation (drawImage.image); //PNG wrap 
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithData:pngdata];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: Huge thanks! This works well, the image is saved faster than the compressed JPG and is artifact-free. The image is saved with transparancy, resulting in a black background when viewed on the iPad.  I have to figure out how to include a white background before writing the PNG.

Comment: This works, but not very elegant: `drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white_background.png"]];` Is it possible to programatically turn off transparency on PNG writes?